# What are the necessary imports for unit testing with Mockito?

Tags: java, annotations, mockito

I'm using Mockito version 1.9.0.  I've looked around and have found that most examples ignore the list of imports, and other examples are very inconsistent with one another.  I'm getting "error: cannot find symbol" for some of the annotations.  I might be mixing junit syntax in with Mockito syntax, but I'm not sure.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeControllerTest {
  @Mock
  private SomeServiceImpl someService;

  @InjectMocks
  private SomeController someController;

  @Before 
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
  ...
  }

  @Test
  public void testSomething() throws SomeException {
  ...
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Here's what I'm currently importing:

```
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

usually you are fine with :

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

With today's IDE,  they provide autocompletion, and they will lookup upper classes. For example Mockito class is designed in this way, if you try to use the Mockito `eq` matcher, IntelliJ will import `org.mockito.Matchers.eq`

In the same way you could use the `given` family methods ti use BDD style when stubbing instead of `when` family methods, it will import `org.mockito.BDDMockito` which extends the `Mockito` class.

Annotation are all here in `org.mockito`

```
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
```

For some reason regarding code organisation, other stuff might be found elsewhere like :

```
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

**EDIT** : In Mockito 2.x, `org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner` is deprecated, JUnit related code has been moved to `org.mockito.junit`, as such the import should be replaced by :

```
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

Same for the new `MockitoRule`.

```
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoRule;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJunit;
```

But it shouldn't be an issue to find it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I still get the error: "cannot find symbol" for the line that has @Before.  I'll add what I have in my imports section to the question.

Comment: If Before annotation is the issue then I believe your IDE might have issues with `@Before` from junit. The correct import is the one that David mentionned. Also I'm not a huge fan of the star in imports it can lead to have collision with identifiers that have the same name. You might want to be sure that you have the correct JUnit dependency, I've seen transitive dependencies that replaced JUnit 4 by JUnit 3.

Comment: I agree with Brice. I think you have to check your dependencies. @Before is in the junit jar. Which IDE do you use and which dependency management system (ie. Maven)? When I use IntelliJ I have no problem finding the imports for your source example.